# How can I simulate physics steps in advance?

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

Think of the trajectory of two objects that will collide in the future. I want to display this collision as a prediction, so that the player can do something to avoid the collision.

At my disposal is the linear velocity at t_0, but if I only add that to my current position I just get a straight line (obviously) but if I save it in an object with python, this value will be available at the next timestep t_1 and I can reconstruct the change of velocity from that.

If I assume this change to be constant I can get to some curve, which is better, but it's still nowhere near what the gameobject will actually do.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, simulating motion in general is a pretty broad problem. What kinds of forces act on your objects? For example, are your objects falling under the force of gravity? Are they rolling on a curved surface?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use four ray sensors, info can be found [here from blender api](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bge.types.KX_RaySensor.html#bge.types.KX_RaySensor).
Depending on what you are doing, you may want use radar.

From that if some sensor collides with some obj you can get the distance `obj1.getDistanceTo(obj2)`, world trajectory and speed`obj2.localLinearVelocity` in m/s.

Anyway, I come up with this, the trajectory. I hope its useful.

```
from bge import logic
from mathutils import Vector
import math

class vehicle:

    def __init__(self, body):
        self.cont = logic.getCurrentController().owner
        self.body = body
        self.front_ray = self.cont.sensors["front_ray"]
        self.main = self.moving
        pass

    def moving(self):
        velocity = Vector((0,40,0))
        velocity.magnitude = 4
        self.body.setLinearVelocity(velocity,1)
        self.body.applyRotation((0,0,0.02),1)
        if self.front_ray.hitObject:
            self.check_thread(self.front_ray.hitObject)
            pass
        pass

    def check_thread(self, obj):
        rot_obj = obj.localOrientation.to_euler()
        self_rot = self.body.localOrientation.to_euler()
        max_angle_limit = math.radians(-160)
        min_angle_limit = math.radians(-200)

        if rot_obj.z < max_angle_limit and rot_obj.z > min_angle_limit:
            print("ALARM : COLLISION DETECTION FROM :", self.front_ray)

        pass

def main(cont):
    own = cont.owner

    if not "init" in own:
        own['init'] = True
        own['vehicle'] = vehicle(own)

    own['vehicle'].main()
```

[image]